# Problems opening 3GP files in Sony Vegas 12 64bit

Tags: codec, vegas-pro

My system crashed and i reinstalled windows, including Vegas.  Projects that included 3GP files (GSpot says that the codec is MP4V), now cant link the 3GP files.  Vegas says files are offline, i search and relink, but in the end it gives an error and files stay offline.

I have reinstalled (and rebooted) Cole2k, VLC, XVid and still no results.

VLC opens the files, no problem.

Any suggestions?

PS:  yes, 3GP did open up before - the generated sfk files are right alongside the 3GP files.

Comment: I had a related issue with mp4v in avi. https://video.stackexchange.com/a/10011/3643

Answer (score 1):

I finally got back in working order by also installing AviDemux and Quicktime.

CONCLUSION: Vegas is capable of opening 3GP files AS LONG it has the right codecs, which Quicktime seems to supply when installed alongside other codec packs.